# Entity Framework Fluent API generating extra columns in sql on related object

Tags: configuration, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have a pre-existing data model, originally using EF 4 to access.  Updating to EF 6, encountering issues with the changes in syntax for configuration, and defining the relationships to query properly.

In this specific case, my foreign key relationship is generating two columns in the SQL, one I defined, one from nowhere...

I have the following two objects - Company and AppUser:

```
public class Company : EntityBase, IComparable<Company>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<AppSystem> AppSystems { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
    public string PortalCustomerName { get; set; }
}

public class AppUser : EntityBase
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public FlowStatus FlowStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<AppUserRole> AppUserRoles { get; set; }
}

public abstract class EntityBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The id assigned by the system.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration for the two classes:

```
public class CompanyConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
    public CompanyConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Company");
        Property(c => c.Id).HasColumnName("CompanyID");
        Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        Property(c => c.PortalCustomerName).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        HasMany(c => c.AppSystems);
        HasMany(c => c.AppUsers);
    }
}

public class AppUserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AppUser>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AppUserConfiguration"/> class with default values.
    /// </summary>
    public AppUserConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("AppUser");
        Property(u => u.Id).HasColumnName("AppUserId");
        Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(256).IsRequired();
        Property(u => u.FirstName).HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(u => u.LastName).HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(u => u.FlowStatus.Value).HasColumnName("FlowStatus");
        HasRequired(u => u.Company).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("CompanyID"));
    }
}
```

Data models are:
[image]  [image]

When I query companies, no problem, I get SQL that matches

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[CompanyID] AS [CompanyID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[PortalCustomerName] AS [PortalCustomerName]
FROM [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent1]
WHERE N'Joe''s Diner' = [Extent1].[Name]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Name] ASC
```

However, when I query AppUsers I'm having a problem with the queries.  With the configuration above, I get a correct request for CompanyId but I also get an extra column, Company_Id1:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[AppUserId] AS [AppUserId], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Extent1].[FlowStatus] AS [FlowStatus], 
[Extent1].[CompanyID] AS [CompanyID], 
**[Extent1].[Company_Id1] AS [Company_Id1]**
FROM [dbo].[AppUser] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[AppUserId] > 0) AND (N'Joe' = [Extent1].[LastName])
```

But if I remove the mapping and just end the configuration with "HasMany()", the correct map goes away, and Company_Id1 becomes "Company_Id":

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[AppUserId] AS [AppUserId], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Extent1].[FlowStatus] AS [FlowStatus], 
[Extent1].[Company_Id] AS [Company_Id]
FROM [dbo].[AppUser] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[AppUserId] > 0) AND (N'Joe' = [Extent1].[LastName])
```

What's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main flaw of using `EntityTypeConfiguration` is configuring the relationships. The problem is that relationship usually involves two entities, but needs to be configured (properly) just once. The configuration must reflect exactly the navigation and FK properties present.

In your case you have two confilicting configurations of one and the same relationship:

*Company:*

```
HasMany(c => c.AppUsers);
```

*AppUser:*

```
HasRequired(u => u.Company).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("CompanyID"));
```

Note the parameterless `WithMany` in the second configuration.

As a rule of thumb, always configure the relationship in one place. Since `Has` methods require navigation property and `With` doesn't, do it in the configuration for the entity with the navigation property. If both entity have navigation properties for the relationship, then use either one (but still do it only once).

Applying to your scenario, since both your entities have navigation property, either remove the existing line from `Company` configuration and use the following in the `AppUser` configuration:

```
HasRequired(u => u.Company).WithMany(c => c.AppUsers).Map(m => m.MapKey("CompanyID"));
```

or remove the existing line from `AppUser` configuration and use the following in the `Company` configuration:

```
HasMany(c => c.AppUsers).WithRequired(u => u.Company).Map(m => m.MapKey("CompanyID"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation - as you can see I solved the issue but I wasn't clear on why.  Your explanation clarifies - I need to define the relationship in ONE place only.  Following that thinking, I completely removed the reference to Company from AppUserConfiguration and kept the definition in Company and got the same SQL.   That said - any thoughts on where the right place to define the relationships is?  I'm thinking that in a case where the "child" (user) depends on the "parent" (company), that the relationship would be better defined in the "child".

Comment: WRT navigation - in this case, if we navigate between the entities at all, it'll be from user to company, so that further underlines that at least in this case, relationship definition belongs in user (and eventually AppSystems - once I get around to re-incorporating it in my project as I migrate the objects...)

Comment: As I mentioned, when you have bidirectional navigation, it's just a matter of taste. But when you have unidirectional navigation (some people put only collection, some - only the reference), then you have to start with the entity with navigation property - `Has` methods require property accessor, `With` have parameterless overloads.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I solved it myself.  I modified CompanyConfiguration to:

```
 HasMany(c => c.AppUsers).WithRequired(u=>u.Company).Map(u=>u.MapKey("CompanyId"));
```

And changed AppUserConfiguration

```
 HasRequired(u => u.Company);
```

Apparently by moving the mapping definition to the primary object (Company) I've told EF - Company can be used by many users, users must have one company, and identify it as "CompanyId"

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[AppUserId] AS [AppUserId], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Extent1].[FlowStatus] AS [FlowStatus], 
[Extent1].[CompanyId] AS [CompanyId]
FROM [dbo].[AppUser] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[AppUserId] > 0) AND (N'Joe' = [Extent1].[LastName])
```